# How do I assign unique "Name" tag to the EC2 instance(s)?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using Terraform 0.12.  I am trying to build EC2 in bulk for a project and instead of sequentially naming the ec2's I will to name the instances by providing unique names.

I think of using dynamic tags, however, not quite sure how to incorporate in the code.

```
resource "aws_instance" "tf_server" {
  count         = var.instance_count
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  ami           = data.aws_ami.server_ami.id
  associate_public_ip_address = var.associate_public_ip_address

##This provides sequential name.
  tags = {
    Name = "tf_server-${count.index +1}"
  }

  key_name               = "${aws_key_pair.tf_auth.id}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${var.security_group}"]
  subnet_id              = "${element(var.subnets, count.index)}"
}
```

Comment: What kind of name did you want to give them if you don't want to just increment the number suffix?

Comment: It could be server a, server b, server c.  Once option is create multiple resource record and give the name, however I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Why do you not want it to just be a number then? It seems like you don't have a clear requirement here so why complicate it?

Comment: the requirement is that we need to have unique names based on the function of the server vs sequential names

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you can pass the list of VM names as a terraform variable and use count.index to get the name from a specific position in the list based on the count.

```
# variables.tf
# Length of list should be the same as the count of instances being created
variable "instance_names" {
  default = ["apple", "banana", "carrot"]
}
```

```
#main.tf
resource "aws_instance" "tf_server" {
  count         = var.instance_count
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  ami           = data.aws_ami.server_ami.id
  associate_public_ip_address = var.associate_public_ip_address

##This provides names as per requirement from the list.
  tags = {
    Name = "${element(var.instance_names, count.index)}"
  }

  key_name               = "${aws_key_pair.tf_auth.id}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${var.security_group}"]
  subnet_id              = "${element(var.subnets, count.index)}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would the following be similar to what you are after?

Define a list of name prefixes as a variable and then cycle through the naming prefixes using the element function.

```
variable "name_prefixes" {
  default = ["App", "Db", "Web"]
}

...

##This provides sequential name.
  tags = {
    Name = "${element(var.name_prefixes, count.index)}${count.index + 1}"
  }
...
```

The result would be App1, Db2, Web3, App4, Db5... The numbering is not ideal, but at least you would have a distinct name per instance.

The only way I can think of naming them sequentially (e.g. App1, App2, Db1, Db2 etc.) would require an individual resource for each type of instance and then just use count.index on the name like your original code.

Comment: Thanks @tedsmitt, I think I will probably have to go by creating each resource and tag as requested by the client.

Comment: No problem, sorry couldn't be of more assistance!